# What does 'creating a web sphere commerce instance' mean

Tags: database, instance

What does 'creating a web sphere commerce instance' mean and it is given that for wcs version 6,  'WebSphere Commerce supports a one to one mapping between the WebSphere Commerce instance and the WebSphere Commerce database.Running multiple WebSphere Commerce instances against the same database is not supported.'Could anyone tell about the instances for wcs 6?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained very clearly in the WebSphere Commerce documentation here. WebSphere Commerce is currently in Version 7 with FEP8 as most recent announced feature pack. Why are looking at WCS 6 ?

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/concepts/ccmwebspherecommerceinstance.htm

To quote -
The WebSphere Commerce instance consists of four main parts:
    A Java Platform, Enterprise Edition Archive (EAR) deployed to and running in the WebSphere Application Server.
    A relational database and schema that runs in your chosen database management system.
    Metadata about the deployed EAR and database. This metadata is stored in the WebSphere Commerce installation directory and includes basic information that WebSphere Commerce tools and utilities require to locate and access the EAR and database.
    A web Server configuration. Each instance has a separate web server process.